# How to add a unique constraint on two fields with PonyORM

Tags: python, constraints, unique-constraint, ponyorm

I use PonyORM, and I want to add a unique constraint on a combination of two fields.

Here's an example (PonyEditor link : https://editor.ponyorm.com/user/lial_slasher/DoubleConstraint).

I have two tables, **Parent** and **Child**. A parent can have many childs, but not two with the same name. Which means I want to add a unique constraint on the couple (parent, name) of the Child table.

It's pretty straightforward, but I can't figure out the python syntax to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `composite_key` which according to the document, is equivalent to `UNIQUE` on several columns in SQL.

example:

```py
from pony.orm import *
db = Database()

class Parent(db.Entity):
    name = Required(str)
    children = Set("Child")

class Child(db.Entity):
    parent = Required(Parent)
    name = Required(str)
    composite_key(parent_id, name)
```

Here, the `name` attribute in the `Child` class will be unique together with the `parent` which means each parent can have exactly one child with a specific name. This is equal to the following SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.child
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('child_id_seq'::regclass),
    parent integer NOT NULL,
    name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT child_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT unq_child__name_parent UNIQUE (name, parent),
    CONSTRAINT fk_child__parent FOREIGN KEY (parent)
        REFERENCES public.parent (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

Comment: Would this set the primary key of `Child` to a tuple ? I want to have an auto-incrementing integer as my primary key.

Comment: No it would not. It'll just add an `CONSTRAINT ... UNIQUE(name, parent)` on the child. I edited the answer with more details.

Comment: OK. I was convinced it would be used as a primary key, that's why I was not using `composite_key`. Well, thanks a lot, I'll flag this response as answer.